# Apply VideoTexture on a loaded .obj doesn't works three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I load an .obj exported from sketchup and representing a simple rectangle.
I want to apply a video texture on the front face of loaded .obj but it doesn't work and no error on the console. I'm quite stuck,the problem may come the UV, but I found nothing which can help me. I tried to use a VideoTexture but same problems.
here my code:

```
    <div id="ThreeJS" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px"></div>

    <video id="video" autoplay muted loop crossOrigin="anonymous" webkit-playsinline style="display:none">
        <source src="assets/output.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>


    <script>
        var AMOUNT = 100;
        var container;
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var video, image, imageContext,
        imageReflection, imageReflectionContext, imageReflectionGradient,
        texture, textureReflection;
        var mesh;
        var mouseX = 0;
        var mouseY = 0;
        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );

            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
            camera.position.z = 1000;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf0f0f0 );

            video = document.createElement( 'video' );
            // video.id = 'video';
            // video.type = ' video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis" ';
            video.src = "assets/output.mp4";
            video.load(); // must call after setting/changing source
            video.muted = true;
            video.play();
            //
            image = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
            image.width = 480;
            image.height = 204;
            imageContext = image.getContext( '2d' );
            imageContext.fillStyle = '#000000';
            imageContext.fillRect( 0, 0, 480, 204 );
            texture = new THREE.Texture( image );

            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 } );
            imageReflection = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
            imageReflection.width = 480;
            imageReflection.height = 204;
            imageReflectionContext = imageReflection.getContext( '2d' );
            imageReflectionContext.fillStyle = '#000000';
            imageReflectionContext.fillRect( 0, 0, 480, 204 );
            imageReflectionGradient = imageReflectionContext.createLinearGradient( 0, 0, 0, 204 );
            imageReflectionGradient.addColorStop( 0.2, 'rgba(240, 240, 240, 1)' );
            imageReflectionGradient.addColorStop( 1, 'rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.8)' );

            textureReflection = new THREE.Texture( imageReflection );
            var materialReflection = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: textureReflection, side: THREE.BackSide, overdraw: 0.5 } );

            // var plane = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 480, 204, 4, 4 );
            // mesh = new THREE.Mesh( plane, material );
            // mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 1;
            // scene.add(mesh);
            // mesh = new THREE.Mesh( plane, materialReflection );
            // mesh.position.y = -306;
            // mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI;
            // mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 1.5;
            // scene.add( mesh );
            // this works

            //model
        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        loader.load( 'assets/model3D.obj', function (object) {
            var instance;
          object.traverse( function (child) {
              if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                child.material = materialReflection;
                child.material.needsUpdate = true;
                // this doesn't works
              }
            });

          object.position.y = - 80;
          scene.add( object );
        });


            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            //
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        }
        function onWindowResize() {
            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }
        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
            mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
            mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) * 0.2;
        }
        //
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
        }
        function render() {
            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.05;
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );
            if ( video.readyState === video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA ) {
                imageContext.drawImage( video, 0, 0 );
                if ( texture ) texture.needsUpdate = true;
                if ( textureReflection ) textureReflection.needsUpdate = true;
            }
            imageReflectionContext.drawImage( image, 0, 0 );
            imageReflectionContext.fillStyle = imageReflectionGradient;
            imageReflectionContext.fillRect( 0, 0, 480, 204 );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
    </script>
```

here my .obj:

```
# Alias OBJ Model File
# Exported from SketchUp, (c) 2000-2012 Trimble Navigation Limited
# File units = meters

g Mesh1 Model

usemtl FrontColor
v 12.4942 0 7.12249
vt 491.898 280.413
vn 0 -1 0
v 1.26421 0 7.12249
vt 49.7719 280.413
v 1.26421 0 0.472495
vt 49.7719 18.6021
v 12.4942 0 0.472495
vt 491.898 18.6021
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 3/3/1 4/4/1
```

ps: I’m beginner in three.js

Comment: Any way you could get this up and running on a JSFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/ It would make it a lot easier to debug for people trying to help you. Also, you should try getting it to work on a simple ThreeJS-generated plane. Once you get that working, you can try it on an OBJ import. That might help you narrow down whether the problem is in your code, or with the OBJ.

Comment: I will try to make a JSFiddle. I already make it works on a simple ThreeJS plane. The probleme come only when I apply a texture ( video or img) when I use an obj import.